# spring-boot-admin server 1.4.6 doesn't display flayway information

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I've got a spring-boot-admin client witch uses flyway. The actuator works and `{clientServer}/flyway` gives a correct JSON Response. Even if I click `raw JSON` in the Spring-Boot-Admin Server Flyway Tab, the Response looks good.

But there is no Data displayed at `{adminServer}/#/applications/a78d409b/flyway`

ImageAdmin:
[image]
ImageFlywayJSON:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure for flyway endpoint has changed with spring boot 1.5. So you need to wait for the spring boot admin 1.5 release...